# Connect to a remote MQ with WebSphere Message Broker

Tags: ibm-mq, esb, messagebroker

An MQ Input node can only connect to the MQ that is bound to the MessageBroker installation. I would like to connect to a remote MQ. I would like to avoid using the JMS Input.

Would it be possible to use the MQ Service for connecting to a remote MQ?

I'm using tve version 9, so actually the IIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deliver outbound messages to remote queue managers via the broker's queue manager if suitable channels and xmit queues are setup.

This however is not the same as a client connection to a remote queue manager which is not currently supported.

You could use a JCN to call the MQ base API or you could raise a request for enhancement here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532